# namenode can not started in Multi-node cluster in ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, hadoop2

so i follow this guide to setup mu multi-node cluster:http://disi.unitn.it/~lissandrini/notes/installing-hadoop-on-ubuntu-14.html
when i finish all setup and run start-dfs.sh, after that, when i run jps, only have SecondaryNameNode started. 
here is my core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://mynode1/</value>
    <description>NameNode URI</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

and my hdfs.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/data/datanode</value>
    <description>DataNode directory</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:///usr/local/hadoop/data/namenode</value>
    <description>NameNode directory for namespace and transaction logs storage.</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

and my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

54.225.196.4    mynode1
54.80.40.198    mynode2

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

This is my namenode log

```
2014-10-26 01:16:57,756 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ip-10-169-41-62.ec2.internal/10.169.41.62
STARTUP_MSG:   args = []
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.4.1
```

The thing i notice is if i change everything in the setting from mynode1 to localhost, then seem namenode can get started, but datanode in node2 will not response to master, which i cant upload a file to hdfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use this tutorial [here](http://letsdobigdata.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/setting-up-hadoop-1-2-1-multi-node-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-part-2/). I used it and everything was working fine, I had just changing the port number from 8020 t0 9000, and 8021 to 9001.

The core and hdfs files are not correct. I cannot understand how many nodes you are deploying. So, change your tutorial as I refereed you in the above link, and if you have any issue just let me know.

Comment: Hi, I'm the author of the tutorial there. If that is wrong in some part, please let me know, I do not want to have confusing/wrong things around. Thanks a lot!